# Filter list of Auto discovered RDS instances in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

Quicksight Enterprise Autodiscovery is showing all RDS instances in the account, but we want to show only the right one on a per user basis.

We have set access to the AWS RDS services and denied the default access for users. Then we have created a new policy for the users that should see the one db instance.
Apparently Quicksight Is using the rds:DescribeDBInstances command to get all instances. How can we limit the statement below to only return the one instance we want? (It seems there are only the AWS General conditions available)

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I would like to only list 1 instance, not all

Comment: This is a long-standing issue and as of today, no solution exists. The "DescribeDBInstances" action is one of the many actions that don't support "resource" filtering and as such is "all or nothing".